# Sort by date (newest)

Tags: php, mysql

Right now I'm sorting by each articles auto_increment id with the query below

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM articles ORDER BY id DESC");
```

I want to know how to sort by a date field I made, that stores the current date via, `strtotime()` it should query the dates from newest to oldest.

Current code

```
$alist = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM articles ORDER BY id DESC");
$results = mysql_num_rows($alist);
    
if ($results > 0){
while($info = mysql_fetch_array($alist)) {
  // query stuff 
  echo $info['time'];
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Just change the column in the ORDER BY:

```
SELECT * FROM articles ORDER BY time DESC
```

Comment: what if my date style like this 12-9-2018 11:32:52 AM?

Answer (score 6):

Let MySQL handle the date stuff - IMO its MUCH better at it than PHP...

add a column with DATE or DATETIME type in your table.  On inserting a new record either use NOW() or set a trigger to do it for you (will have to allow null in the coulmn if you are going to user a trigger)

your query should be:

```
$alist = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM articles ORDER BY `your_date_field` DESC");
```

Comment: can this work if I set my date in varchar but informal of Y-m-d?

Comment: @KarueBensonKarue you will be at the mercy of natural sort order of text in that scenario. If you have a date then I'd suggest you use a type suitable to store it - you get the power offered out of the box dealing with dates then.